# counting post from a wp-query using sticky_post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, sticky

I'm trying to count the number of sticky_posts inside a specific category.

first I get all the sticky posts :

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
```

then here are my args :

```
$args_sticky = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'post__in'  => $sticky,
'post__not_in'  => array($post->ID),
'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID),
);
```

and then I try to count the number of posts from those args :

```
$sticky_number = count($args_sticky);
```

the problem is that I get not the right result. I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

here is my full php code :

```
<?php 
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args_sticky = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'post__in'  => $sticky,
'post__not_in'  => array($post->ID),
'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID),
);


$sticky_number = count($args_sticky); 

echo $sticky_number;
    ?>
```

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 0):

You are not counting the right thing. It should be:

```
$sticky_number = count($sticky);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but when couting $sticky, it counts all the sticky posts from all categories. I'm trying to count the sticky posts from the posts defined in my args. and store the result in a variable.

Comment: @mmdwc, in that case, you need to call `$posts = get_posts($args_sticky)` and then do `count($posts)`.